# How to change the url of a .net 6 web api

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

i wanted to change the launching url of the WebAPI from `https://localhost:7027/controller` to `https://localhost:7027/test/controller`. i have tried adding `app.UsePathBase("/test")` but it only routes swagger. i tried it with postman and it says 404 not found. how do i go about accomplishing this please. thank you

Comment: Your controller should inherit the ControllerBase class and have the [ApiController] attribute and optionally you could add a [Route] attribute to specify that controller's route. For example [Route("test/[controller")]. So if you create an action GetMyName and add a Route attribute [Route("getMyName")] in a Controller with a name MyController it will have url /test/MyController/getMyName. You should have tha app.MapControllers in your Program.cs. Please edit the post and add some of your Program.cs and controller's code, so that we can see how you are configuring the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with attribute routing for a specific controller or

```
[Route("test/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
```

Or globally you can do like below

```
  app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
  {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");
  });
```

See below - [Change the "/api" part of the url in ASP.Net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42424984/change-the-api-part-of-the-url-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: i tried that.. and i get this error..

System.InvalidOperationException: 'Endpoint Routing does not support 'IApplicationBuilder.UseMvc(...)'. To use 'IApplicationBuilder.UseMvc' set 'MvcOptions.EnableEndpointRouting = false' inside 'ConfigureServices(...).'

Comment: I just changed the answer actually after 2.2 version we need to use 'endpoints.MapControllerRoute'

Comment: now i have this error.. System.InvalidOperationException: 'EndpointRoutingMiddleware matches endpoints setup by EndpointMiddleware and so must be added to the request execution pipeline before EndpointMiddleware. Please add EndpointRoutingMiddleware by calling 'IApplicationBuilder.UseRouting' inside the call to 'Configure(...)' in the application startup code.'

Comment: Hi @Danny, you need add `app.UseRouting();` before `app.UseEndpoints()`.

Comment: Yes please add app.UseRouting before app.UseEndPoins as per @Rena's comment